# Calling SOAP in Jersey

Tags: rest, soap, jersey-2.0

I have a requirement from a client which wants to write a wrapper REST web service around a SOAP web service.

I am new to both SOAP and REST. Can anyone please let me know

1. If we can call SOAP web service inside a REST web service?
2. If yes, then how to do it in Jersey 2.0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. There is nothing special about calling a SOAP service from inside a JAX-RS Resouce. Just write a JAX-WS client [as described in the Java EE 7 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxws001.htm#BNAYX).

Comment: I get a 404 for your link.