# Calling SOAP service inside REST service

Tags: java, xml, rest, soap, restlet

I want to code for a REST service using Restlet framework that wraps a third party SOAP service with some XML data. So whenever I call the REST service with some XML data that REST service internally calls that third party SOAP service with the XML data that I provided and the response travels from that third party SOAP API to REST API and from REST API to me.
I have gone through this questions;

[Calling a SOAP service using REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121406/calling-a-soap-service-using-rest-service)

[Calling SOAP in Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986498/calling-soap-in-jersey)

But it didn't help me a lot, So it would be great if anyone provide me the links or tutorial where I can get any help. Thanks.

Comment: I can suggest you the steps to follow if you are familiar then it should good enough.
1. Create RestAPI
2.Create SOAP Client in Rest API 
3.Read the the SOAP response and parse , play with the response as u needed.
write the code and let us know if you have any issues

Comment: I know this steps very well, but I want to know the overall solution. How can I create a SOAP Client in REST API with some XML data?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the following links could help you if you want to implement by hand:

- Restlet tutorial - http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/tutorials/2.3
- Writing a SOAP Client - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/aeqgc/index.html

The key challenge here is to convert request elements into the SOAP request since SOAP only uses HTTP as a transport protocol (both headers and payload) and the same for response (extract headers and payload to build the REST response). With Restlet, you need to leverage its REST API for this. See this link: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/http-headers-mapping.

I also saw these tools that seem to provide a proxy to adapt a SOAP service as REST service:

- Exposing SOAP Services as REST Resources - http://www.membrane-soa.org/service-proxy-doc/4.0/rest2soap-gateway.htm, https://github.com/membrane/service-proxy
- a RESTful API proxy to a SOAP-based service - http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/exposing-soap-service-api-proxy

Hope it helps you,
Thierry